# Adding x and y values while creating a label QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to create a label on a map in QGIS.

I can open the setting where there are an `X` and `Y` button and a few other properties, like opacity and distance.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I need to enter the proper `X` and `Y` coordinate here, but I don't know how to get to where it lets you enter the coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

**For QGIS 3.x (within project only)**

Select `move` from this menu, click on your label, choose your primary key and move it around.

[image]

**For QGIS 2.x and QGIS 3.x (label position stored in attribute table)**

Open your attributetable and create two new fields (e.g. `label_x` and `label_y`). Make sure to set field type to `double` and set `length` and `precision`. (No need to fill these fields with values).

[image]

Now choose these two fields as your data defined source:

[image]

Make sure to enable `edit mode` for your layer.

[image]

After you've done this menu becomes selectable:

[image]

Now just choose `move` and click on your label to move it around.

Note that this can make your map 'usable' at the current scale only.

Comment: `After you've done this menu becomes selectable:`, in QGIS 3, this is already selectable without creating the `label_x` and `label_y` because QGIS will use automatically the auxilliary storage in the project.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll edit my post.

Comment: The QGIS 2 solution is still correct in QGIS 3 if you want the X and Y to be embedded at the layer level. Auxiliary storage is stored at the project level.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Actually a pretty cool feature I've never noticed before. Just edited again..

Comment: Auxilliary storage is new feature in QGIS 3 : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#auxiliary-storage

Comment: What toolbars do I need to get the 2 options circled in your second screenshot?

Comment: The second screenshot is just the attribute table of your layer. Open it by right clicking on your layer and click open attribute table.